# Difference between has_many, belong_to, and both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

What's the difference in the following three scenarios?

```
#Case 1
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment
end 

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :user
end
```

Case 1 has both has_many and belong_to.

```
#Case 2
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment
end 

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Case 2 has only has_many.

```
#Case 3
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end 

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :user
end
```

Case 3 has only belong_to.

Since both has_many and belong_to represent a one-to-many relation, how to we decide which of these three we should use?

Comment: Just as a note, your `has_many` should be plural: `has_many :comments`

Comment: When should we use singular and plural?

Comment: `has_many` = plural (many), `belongs_to` = singular (belongs to only 1). I just noticed your `belongs_to` is wrong too, you left out an "s". Also, you need to use singular if you're using `has_one`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They require the same database schema. The difference is only which methods are defined for you.

When you add `has_many :comments` to `User`, you gain the ability to refer to `user.comments`, and so easily find the comments for a particular user object (and create new ones with `user.comments.build`, and so on).

When you add `belongs_to :user` to `Comment`, you gain the ability to refer to `comment.user`, and so find the user to whom a particular comment object belongs.

These calls simply create convenience methods for you to use when manipulating your model objects. I would suggest using both, because you will likely want to use both and the relationship is clearer to someone reading the code.

Comment: How does it affect server workload? Does using both make more overhead?

Comment: It does not appreciably affect the server workload. The database schema is exactly the same, so the queries you issue are the same.